# Preemtible nodes change state to NotReady every 10-30 min in gcp kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We are facing a problem with one of our kubernetes clusters which uses only preemtible nodes for our staging environment. Essentially nodes change state to NotReady randomly which causes pods to get stuck on rescheduling. We started experiencing this after we upgraded kubernetes to v1.15. We didn't had this issue before. We tried switching off different deployments to pint point if its caused maybe by a certain pod, but so far didn't found any correlation. Any advice would be very helpful at least where to look for cause of NotReady state in the first place. Here is a typical output when checking node states:

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                     STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-0xqr   NotReady   <none>   27m   v1.15.11-gke.9
gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-9cb8   Ready      <none>   27m   v1.15.11-gke.9
gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-jrt6   Ready      <none>   27m   v1.15.11-gke.9
gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-ls7p   NotReady   <none>   17m   v1.15.11-gke.9
gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-r8xr   Ready      <none>   14m   v1.15.11-gke.9
gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-z01r   NotReady   <none>   27m   v1.15.11-gke.9
```

```
gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g   NotReady   <none>   100m   v1.15.11-gke.9
evaldas@evaldas-pc:~$ kubectl describe node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g
Name:               gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=n1-standard-4
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=default-pool
                    cloud.google.com/gke-os-distribution=cos
                    cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible=true
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=europe-west1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=europe-west1-d
                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g
                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    pool-designation=main-pool
Annotations:        container.googleapis.com/instance_id: 100599290254760530
                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    node.gke.io/last-applied-node-labels:
                      beta.kubernetes.io/fluentd-ds-ready=true,cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool=default-pool,cloud.google.com/gke-os-distribution=cos,cloud.google....
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Mon, 15 Jun 2020 09:01:06 +0300
Taints:             cloud.google.com/impending-node-termination:NoSchedule
                    node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Lease:
  HolderIdentity:  gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g
  AcquireTime:     <unset>
  RenewTime:       Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:08 +0300
Conditions:
  Type                          Status    LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                          Message
  ----                          ------    -----------------                 ------------------                ------                          -------
  ReadonlyFilesystem            False     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:57 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:56 +0300   FilesystemIsNotReadOnly         Filesystem is not read-only
  CorruptDockerOverlay2         False     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:57 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:56 +0300   NoCorruptDockerOverlay2         docker overlay2 is functioning properly
  FrequentUnregisterNetDevice   False     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:57 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:56 +0300   NoFrequentUnregisterNetDevice   node is functioning properly
  FrequentKubeletRestart        False     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:57 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:56 +0300   NoFrequentKubeletRestart        kubelet is functioning properly
  FrequentDockerRestart         False     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:57 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:56 +0300   NoFrequentDockerRestart         docker is functioning properly
  FrequentContainerdRestart     False     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:57 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:56 +0300   NoFrequentContainerdRestart     containerd is functioning properly
  KernelDeadlock                False     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:57 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:35:56 +0300   KernelHasNoDeadlock             kernel has no deadlock
  NetworkUnavailable            False     Mon, 15 Jun 2020 09:01:20 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 09:01:20 +0300   RouteCreated                    RouteController created a route
  MemoryPressure                Unknown   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:09 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:52 +0300   NodeStatusUnknown               Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  DiskPressure                  Unknown   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:09 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:52 +0300   NodeStatusUnknown               Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  PIDPressure                   Unknown   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:09 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:52 +0300   NodeStatusUnknown               Kubelet stopped posting node status.
  Ready                         Unknown   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:09 +0300   Mon, 15 Jun 2020 10:36:52 +0300   NodeStatusUnknown               Kubelet stopped posting node status.
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.132.0.60
  ExternalIP:   35.205.52.80
  InternalDNS:  gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g.c.stacktome-prod.internal
  Hostname:     gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g.c.stacktome-prod.internal
Capacity:
  attachable-volumes-gce-pd:  127
  cpu:                        4
  ephemeral-storage:          98868448Ki
  hugepages-2Mi:              0
  memory:                     15397596Ki
  pods:                       110
Allocatable:
  attachable-volumes-gce-pd:  127
  cpu:                        3920m
  ephemeral-storage:          47093746742
  hugepages-2Mi:              0
  memory:                     12698332Ki
  pods:                       110
System Info:
  Machine ID:                 b5baa1dbc20255ae27033ed23ab4e10f
  System UUID:                b5baa1db-c202-55ae-2703-3ed23ab4e10f
  Boot ID:                    bdebb6f0-9267-469e-a9fb-ca330e50f249
  Kernel Version:             4.19.104+
  OS Image:                   Container-Optimized OS from Google
  Operating System:           linux
  Architecture:               amd64
  Container Runtime Version:  docker://19.3.1
  Kubelet Version:            v1.15.11-gke.9
  Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.15.11-gke.9
PodCIDR:                      10.4.119.0/24
ProviderID:                   gce://stacktome-prod/europe-west1-d/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g
Non-terminated Pods:          (4 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                                 CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                   ----                                                 ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  kube-system                 fluentd-gcp-v3.1.1-9z74z                             100m (2%)     1 (25%)     200Mi (1%)       500Mi (4%)     100m
  kube-system                 kube-proxy-gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g    100m (2%)     0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5m15s
  kube-system                 node-termination-handler-jwvqw                       150m (3%)     150m (3%)   30Mi (0%)        30Mi (0%)      100m
  kube-system                 prometheus-to-sd-jctnk                               1m (0%)       3m (0%)     20Mi (0%)        37Mi (0%)      100m
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                   Requests    Limits
  --------                   --------    ------
  cpu                        351m (8%)   1153m (29%)
  memory                     250Mi (2%)  567Mi (4%)
  ephemeral-storage          0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  hugepages-2Mi              0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-gce-pd  0           0
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                    From                                                Message
  ----     ------                   ----                   ----                                                -------
  Normal   Starting                 39m                    kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  39m                    kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  39m (x2 over 39m)      kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    39m (x2 over 39m)      kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     39m (x2 over 39m)      kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Warning  Rebooted                 39m                    kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g has been rebooted, boot id: 893432db-0107-4781-a9a7-05c88def8887
  Normal   NodeReady                39m                    kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeReady
  Normal   Starting                 39m                    kube-proxy, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g  Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   NodeReady                24m                    kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeReady
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  24m                    kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  24m (x2 over 24m)      kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    24m (x2 over 24m)      kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   Starting                 24m                    kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Starting kubelet.
  Warning  Rebooted                 24m                    kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g has been rebooted, boot id: 1632075d-b6b6-4646-979b-88622c79bcd0
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     24m (x2 over 24m)      kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   Starting                 24m                    kube-proxy, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g  Starting kube-proxy.
  Normal   Starting                 5m19s                  kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Starting kubelet.
  Normal   NodeAllocatableEnforced  5m19s                  kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Updated Node Allocatable limit across pods
  Warning  Rebooted                 5m19s                  kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g has been rebooted, boot id: bdebb6f0-9267-469e-a9fb-ca330e50f249
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientMemory  5m18s (x2 over 5m19s)  kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory
  Normal   NodeHasNoDiskPressure    5m18s (x2 over 5m19s)  kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure
  Normal   NodeHasSufficientPID     5m18s (x2 over 5m19s)  kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID
  Normal   NodeReady                5m18s                  kubelet, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g     Node gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g status is now: NodeReady
  Normal   Starting                 5m16s                  kube-proxy, gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2g  Starting kube-proxy.
```

kubelet logs:

```
Default
2020-06-15 09:54:02.097 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handler"
Default
2020-06-15 09:55:00.326 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patchcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controlleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patch", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller"
Default
2020-06-15 10:02:06.111 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.createcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:node:gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gConflict
Default
2020-06-15 10:02:06.187 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patchcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controlleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patch", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller"
Default
2020-06-15 10:02:06.413 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:gcp-controller-managerConflict
Default
2020-06-15 10:02:06.690 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:gcp-controller-manageraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:gcp-controller-manager"
Default
2020-06-15 10:02:39.685 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handler"
Default
2020-06-15 10:08:33.254 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handler"
Default
2020-06-15 10:09:20.685 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patchcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controlleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patch", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller"
Default
2020-06-15 10:16:28.608 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.createcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:node:gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gConflict
Default
2020-06-15 10:16:28.680 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patchcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controlleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patch", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller"
Default
2020-06-15 10:16:28.979 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:gcp-controller-managerConflict
Default
2020-06-15 10:16:29.215 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:gcp-controller-manageraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:gcp-controller-manager"
Default
2020-06-15 10:17:01.589 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handler"
Default
2020-06-15 10:28:05.346 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handler"
Default
2020-06-15 10:28:51.815 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patchcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controlleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patch", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller"
Default
2020-06-15 10:35:58.960 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.createcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:node:gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gConflict
Default
2020-06-15 10:35:59.032 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patchcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controlleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patch", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller"
Default
2020-06-15 10:35:59.250 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:gcp-controller-managerConflict
Default
2020-06-15 10:35:59.479 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:gcp-controller-manageraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:gcp-controller-manager"
Default
2020-06-15 10:36:52.169 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patchcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controlleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patch", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller"
Default
2020-06-15 10:44:14.663 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.createcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:node:gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gConflict
Default
2020-06-15 10:44:14.744 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patchcore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controlleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.patch", principal_email: "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-controller"
Default
2020-06-15 10:44:15.013 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:gcp-controller-managerConflict
Default
2020-06-15 10:44:15.306 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:gcp-controller-manageraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:gcp-controller-manager"
Default
2020-06-15 10:44:48.316 EEST
k8s.ioio.k8s.core.v1.nodes.updatecore/v1/nodes/gke-staging-default-pool-3de3436f-nw2gsystem:serviceaccount:kube-system:node-termination-handleraudit_log, method: "io.k8s.core.v1.nodes.update", principal_email: "system:servic
```

Comment: add kubelet logs from the not ready nodes

Comment: Preemptible nodes last at most 24 hours, but that does not means that this 24 hours is a SLA. If the resources are needed, the zone will kill your VM even if the VM only last a couple of minutes. Do not use preemptible nodes for GKE.

Comment: Add describe of one of the notReady nodes

Comment: added extra logs and description for notready node, you can see that its getting rebooted for some reason but not really clear why and it doesn't like its due to resource constraints from GCP side. Yes I'm aware of 24 limit, but from our experience it usually was 1-2 times per day nodes being recycled, which is ok for our use cases.

Comment: This behaviour occurs only on v1.15.11-gke.9? Did you create those pools using GUI or CLI? Does the same issue occurs on newer version like 1.15.11-gke.15? Its Regional or Zonal cluster?

Comment: @PjoterS yes we saw same behavior in 1.15.11-gke.15 and 1.16 also. Pools created via CLI. All nodes are in 1 zone=europe-west1-d

Comment: Could you share with us what command did you use? You mentioned that you created node-pool using CLI. Did you do the same with cluster? Does your commands looked like: `gcloud container node-pools create [pool-name] --preemptible --cluster [cluster-name] --node-version=1.15.11-gke.9 --zone=europe-west1-d --num-nodes=6`, did you use any other flag?

Comment: @PjoterS sorry actually I just got confirmed that we used gcp web console for creation, we'll try just CLI again to see if there is any difference and update later here.

Comment: @EvaldasMiliauskas Any update? Issue still occurs? Are you able to provide scenario for reproducing this issue?

Comment: @PjoterS strangely we're not seeing this issue anymore at least not as often as before, we tried with cli creating another cluster but initially it shown signs of same behavior, but for the last 10 days or so nodes seemed to have 'stabilized'. Unfortunately I can't say how to reproduce it for now.

Comment: actually we're still experiencing same behavior yet again, unfortunately it appears to be a bit random, maybe it relates to how preemptive nodes get rolled over but it doesn't seem like its the main cause as the node itself doesn't get removed just restarted